# Using shellspec for testing

Tags: unit-testing, bdd

I try to implement a testing framework using **shellspec**.
I have read the  [article](https://shellspec.info/) and README at [shellspec github project](https://github.com/shellspec/shellspec).
But I`m still confused about how to customise projects directories.

I`d like to have the next structure of my testing framework:

```
<root_dir>
  |-- README
  |
  |-- tests
       |
       |-- test_instance_1
       |    |
       |    |-- lib
       |    |    |
       |    |    |-- my_test_1.sh
       |    |
       |    |-- spec
       |         |
       |         |-- my_test_1_spec.sh
       |
       |
       |-- test_instance_2
            |
            |-- lib
            |    |
            |    |-- my_test_2.sh
            |
            |-- spec
                 |
                 |-- my_test_2_spec.sh
```

As it is mentioned at [shellspec github project](https://github.com/shellspec/shellspec), it is possible to customise directory structure:

> This is the typical directory structure. Version 0.28.0 allows many of
> these to be changed by specifying options, supporting a more flexible
> [directory structure](https://github.com/shellspec/shellspec/blob/master/docs/directory_structure.md).

So I tried to modify my **.shellspec** file in the following way:

```
--default-path "***/spec"
--execdir @basedir/lib`
```

But when I run shellspec command in my command line, I get the next errors:

```
shellspec.sh: eval: line 23: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
shellspec.sh: eval: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

shellspec is run in <root_dir>.

Also I saw that there should be **.shellspec-basedir** file in each subdirectory, but I don`t realise, what it should contain.

I'd be happy, if someone give an example of existing project with custome directory structure or tell me, what I`m doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be very simple. Need to use

```
--default-path "**/spec"
```

to find *_spec.sh* files in all spec/ directories in the project